# How do I use Docker environment variable in ENTRYPOINT array?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I set an environment variable, say `ENV ADDRESSEE=world`, and I want to use it in the entry point script concatenated into a fixed string like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./greeting", "--message", "Hello, world!"]
```

with `world` being the value of the environment varible, how do I do it? I tried using `"Hello, $ADDRESSEE"` but that doesn't seem to work, as it takes the `$ADDRESSEE` literally.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

You're using the **exec form** of ENTRYPOINT. Unlike the **shell form**, the **exec form** does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, `ENTRYPOINT [ "echo", "$HOME" ]` will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the **shell form** or execute a shell directly, for example: `ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`.
When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.(from [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example))

In your case, I would use **shell form**

```
ENTRYPOINT ./greeting --message "Hello, $ADDRESSEE\!"
```

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT java -jar /dockertest.jar -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dserver.port=$port` while `ENV port=123`. The port ENV is not resolved. Any ideas why?

Comment: While it works, it appears to create some new problems, like not including the passed arguments to that entrypoint. For example you can't add a `--attitude "shouting"` argument to the `docker run` command which should get passed to `./greeting`

Comment: Use `ENTRYPOINT ./greeting --message "Hello, $ADDRESSEE\! $0 $@"` if you also want to pass additional variables to `./greeting` via the `docker run` invocation (or to pass the `CMD` of the Dockerfile)

Comment: Note that the shell form can cause signals to not be passed through to the process (`greeting` in your example). https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/

Comment: can I get the value of an environment variable in exec form , like `[myexecutable.sh , "$variable"] , I can do it by ["sh", "-c" , "echo $var"] , but not in this way

Comment: @jbg agreed. What if we use `ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]`? Does this also have the same issue of signals not being propagated?

Comment: @vitr - any reason NOT to use the shell form? Why bother with the exec form?

Comment: @jtlz2 many containers don't have a shell, and it can interfere with your application

Comment: This response assumes that `/bin/sh` is available, which is not the case with an image based on `scratch`. Is there any way to do it with the `exec` form?

Comment: Note: Surround this variable with double quotes; otherwise, it can lead to unexpected behavior

Answer (score 34):

After much pain, and **great assistance** from @vitr et al above, i decided to try

- standard bash substitution
- *shell form* of *ENTRYPOINT* (great tip from above)

and that worked.

```
ENV LISTEN_PORT=""

ENTRYPOINT java -cp "app:app/lib/*" hello.Application --server.port=${LISTEN_PORT:-80}
```

e.g.

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 -d --env LISTEN_PORT=8080 my-image
```

and

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:80 -d my-image
```

both set the port correctly in my container

### Refs

see https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Answer (score 30):

I tried to resolve with the suggested answer and still ran into some issues...

This was a solution to my problem:

```
ARG APP_EXE="AppName.exe"
ENV _EXE=${APP_EXE}

# Build a shell script because the ENTRYPOINT command doesn't like using ENV
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n mono ${_EXE}" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

# Run the generated shell script.
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Specifically targeting your problem:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n ./greeting --message ${ADDRESSEE}" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: it seems  your answer doesn't provide complete solutions the OP's question

Comment: I suppose I don't understand how it doesn't provide a solution to the OP's question ... I updated with an example to solve with the exact question in mind.

Comment: you mentioned still you ran into some issues!!

Comment: correct, which is why I introduced a new solution. ... the "accepted" answer didn't work for me, so I echo out to a shell script and that worked.

Comment: So writing the script to a file inside the dockerfile is the correct way to go about it? I think not.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing your approach then @ReverendTim ;)

Answer (score 15):

For me, I wanted to store the name of the script in a variable and still use the exec form.

***Note**: Make sure, the variable you are trying to use is declared an environment variable either from the commandline or via the `ENV` directive.*

Initially I did something like:

```bash
ENTRYPOINT [ "${BASE_FOLDER}/scripts/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

But obviously this didn't work because we are using the **shell** form and the first program listed needs to be an executable on the `PATH`. So to fix this, this is what I ended up doing:

```bash
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "exec ${BASE_FOLDER}/scripts/entrypoint.sh \"${@}\"", "--" ]
```

***Note** the double quotes are required*

What this does is to allow us to take whatever extra args were passed to `/bin/bash`, and supply those same arguments to our script after the name has been resolved by bash.

---

[man 7 bash](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)

> --
>      A -- signals the end of options and disables further
> option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated
> as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is
> equivalent to --.

P.S. `--` also works with any POSIX-compliant shell. See [Utility Syntax Guides](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Comment: This works great. Without `"--"` bash will steal the first argument and never give it to the script, and `"--"` makes things work as expected. However, two improvements. 1) The command should start with `exec`: `"exec ${BASE_FOLDER}/..."`. Otherwise the script/executable won't receive signals properly. 2) It should be `\"${@}\"` and not just `${@}` for proper handling quoted arguments that are passed to CMD.

Comment: @Mike what kind of signals will not be received?

Comment: @smac98 According to [ENTRYPOINT docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint), if shell is parent process, it will not propagate `SIGTERM` to your script when `docker stop ...` is ran. You can search for more info on "docker pid 1 signal", or read, for example, about it in [Google's best practices](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/best-practices-for-building-containers?hl=tr#solution_1_run_as_pid_1_and_register_signal_handlers). Also, please also note that single quotes are not allowed for `ENTRYPOINT` array elements, they need to be double-quoted.

Comment: @Mike, I don't think adding `exec` will fix that problem. If a script contains the following: `sleep 10;echo foo | tee --append /tmp/foo.out` (don't forget the `#!/bin/bash`), I would expect that if we run this script with `exec` as you suggested, then immediately press CTRL+Z i.e. `SIGSTOP`, that the sleep command will stop as well, but this is not the case. The `sleep` command keeps running, and if you wait long enough before resuming the script, after it resumes, it will not keep sleeping, but immediately print `foo`. Maybe I'm missing something here, but is that what you expect?

Comment: @Mike this behavior is no different from a script that is started with just bash as the parent, without `exec`

Comment: The case you described is when `bash` started from `ENTRYPOINT` execs into another `bash` which runs your script. If we assume bash has issues dealing with signals properly, it should not be used as the actual process that's tested. Secondly, I'm not sure what platform you're using, normally Ctrl-Z sends `SIGTSTP`, not `SIGSTOP`. In order to really test what happens you need to cause `SIGTERM` signal which is generated when you run `docker stop`.

Comment: This assumes that `/bin/bash` is available. :(

Comment: @dolmen At the time of writing, yes, I assumed bash because that's what I was using and that's where I discovered a solution. In case you're referring to the use of `--`, that's a standard posix compliant shell option. See [Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) and this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean). As long as the shell you are using is posix-compliant, you are free to assume this answer works with it.

Answer (score 15):

## **I SOLVED THIS VERY SIMPLY!**

> ***IMPORTANT:*** The variable which you wish to use in the `ENTRYPOINT` ***MUST*** be **`ENV`** type (and not `ARG` type).

### *EXAMPLE #1:*

```sh
ARG APP_NAME=app.jar                    # $APP_NAME can be ARG or ENV type.
ENV APP_PATH=app-directory/$APP_NAME    # $APP_PATH must be ENV type.
ENTRYPOINT java -jar $APP_PATH
```

> This will result with executing:
> `java -jar app-directory/app.jar`

### *EXAMPLE #2 (YOUR QUESTION):*

```sh
ARG ADDRESSEE="world"                       # $ADDRESSEE can be ARG or ENV type.
ENV MESSAGE="Hello, $ADDRESSEE!"            # $MESSAGE must be ENV type.
ENTRYPOINT ./greeting --message $MESSAGE
```

> This will result with executing:
> `./greeting --message Hello, world!`

- Please verify to be sure, whether you need *quotation-marks* `""` when assigning string variables.

---

> ***MY TIP:*** Use `ENV` instead of `ARG` whenever possible to avoid confusion on your part or the `SHELL` side.

Comment: Just in case, it's possible to have ENV customizable: `ARG TEST; ENV TEST="${TEST:-foo}"`. Related: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#substitute-environment-variables-in-compose-files https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: This assumes that `/bin/sh` is available. :(

Comment: The relevant Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/reference/dockerfile/#shell-and-exec-form

Answer (score 3):

In my case worked this way: (for Spring boot app in docker)

```
ENTRYPOINT java -DidMachine=${IDMACHINE} -jar my-app-name
```

and passing the params on docker run

```
docker run --env IDMACHINE=Idmachine -p 8383:8383 my-app-name
```

Comment: Just be aware, that when you use the shell-Form, your Java-Process will not receive the SIGTERM signal, since this is sent to the PID 1. And the Process with the PID=1 is the Shell process.

Therefore, your Java-Process will only get killed brutally with a SIGKILL and cannot shutdown gracefully.

See https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/

Comment: This assumes that `/bin/sh` is available. :(

Answer (score 2):

The previous answers suggest to use the shell form.
In my case this was not an option as by using it the **signals can't reach the process** itself.

See point 1 here https://hynek.me/articles/docker-signals/

If the json syntax could resolve variables, this would be what I wanted:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["${APP_NAME}"]
```

If you create a file to run like this:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n ${APP_NAME}" > ./entrypoint.sh
```

You lose the signals as well because a new shell will be created.

See point 2 and use **exec**

The final form that worked for me:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n exec ${APP_NAME}" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: I got "exec ./entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory" on similar command: ```RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n set -e \n geth --unlock 0x367103555b34Eb9a46D92833e7293D540bFd7143 --password /tmp/pwd.txt --keystore /tmp/keystore \n" > ./tmp/entrypoint.sh```, but when I put this into a separate file on the host machine and do ```COPY``` it works. Someone posted there is might be 'end of line' issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "source ~/.bashrc && ./entrypoint.sh ${@}", "--" ]
```

Now you can supply whatever arguments to the `docker run` command and still read all environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using a variation on "create a custom script" approach above. Like this:

```
FROM hairyhenderson/figlet
ENV GREETING="Hello"
RUN printf '#!/bin/sh\nfiglet -W \${GREETING} \$@\n' > /runme && chmod +x /runme
ENTRYPOINT ["/runme"]
CMD ["World"]
```

Run like

```
docker container run -it --rm -e GREETING="G'Day" dockerfornovices/figlet-greeter Alec
```

Comment: This assumes that `/bin/sh` is available. :(

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to pass an `ARG` or `ENV` variable to **exec form** of ENTRYPOINT then a temp file created during image building process might be used.

In my case I had to start the app differently depending on whether the .NET app has been published as self-contained or not.
What I did is I created the temp file and I used its name in the `if` statement of my bash script.

Part of my dockerfile:

```sh
ARG SELF_CONTAINED=true #ENV SELF_CONTAINED=true also works
# File has to be used as a variable as it's impossible to pass variable do ENTRYPOINT using Exec form. File name allows to check whether app is self-contained
RUN touch ${SELF_CONTAINED}.txt
COPY run-dotnet-app.sh .
ENTRYPOINT ["./run-dotnet-app.sh", "MyApp" ]
```

`run-dotnet-app.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME=$1

if [ -f "true.txt" ]; then
   ./"${FILENAME}"
else
   dotnet "${FILENAME}".dll
fi
```

Answer (score -2):

Came here looking for `.envfile` info for `docker run` commands and ended up finding the answer elsewhere, but thought I'd share for others:

This was key for understanding .envfile synax:

> This file should use the syntax `<variable>=value` (which sets the variable to the given value)
> or  (which takes the value from the local environment), and # for comments.

I found the this at https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

In other words, don't do `VAR1=$SOME_OTHER_ENV_VAR`