# Unable to use variables in the Docker Entrypoint command

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a dockerfile. I earlier tried using hard coded paths for my project and the output was fine. However, as soon as I started using a variable, the java code stopped executing.

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:7
EXPOSE 7100

ARG version
ENV version=$version
RUN echo $version

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/$version/logs
RUN ls -tlr /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/

RUN mkdir -p /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel
ADD target/predictionDependencies/star /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel/ #star here is the operator (*), it was being interpret as comments by this stackoverflow editor. 

ADD /target/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar

ADD /target/instance.properties /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/instance.properties

ADD /target/logback.xml /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/logback.xml

RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/$version/
RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/
RUN ls -ltr /cacheDir/services/predictionmodel

ENTRYPOINT java -server -Xmx2g -Xloggc:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/$version/logs/gc.log -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/$version/oom.dump -Dlogback.configurationFile=/cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/logback.xml -Dlog.home=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/$version/logs -Dlogback.debug=true -Dbroker.l^Ct=sv-kafka6.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka7.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka8.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka9.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092 -jar /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar 7100 /cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/$version/instance.properties /com/wizecommerce/services/qa &
```

Command used to build the image.

```
docker build --build-arg version=0.0.14-SNAPSHOT -t prediction:0.0.14-SNAPSHOT .
```

The image seems to be successful. However, when I run the command, the container just exits on it own. Run command used:

```
docker run -p 7100:7100 -v ~/PredictionVolume/logs/:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/0.0.14-SNAPSHOT/logs/  -t prediction:0.0.14-SNAPSHOT
```

And when tried to view the running container, it wasn't running.

I tried working with these tow solutions which I have found but none seems to work.

[How do I use Docker environment variable in ENTRYPOINT array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array)

Other solution was that I used the replaced the following ENTRYPOINT command with this one.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java","-server","-Xmx2g","-Xloggc:/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/${version}/logs/gc.log","-verbose:gc","-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps","-XX:+PrintGCDetails","-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError","-XX:HeapDumpPath=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/${version}/oom.dump","-Dlogback.configurationFile=/cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/${version}/logback.xml","-Dlog.home=/cacheDir/services/live/prediction/p7100/${version}/logs","-Dlogback.debug=true","-Dbroker.l^Ct=sv-kafka6.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka7.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka8.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092,sv-kafka9.pv.sv.nextag.com:9092","-jar","/cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/${version}/prediction-0.0.13-SNAPSHOT.jar","7100","/cacheDir/services/releases/prediction/p7100/${version}/instance.properties","/com/wizecommerce/services/qa","&"]
```

But with this command the output comes like, if you type java on the terminal showing all the options available to use will be shown on the screen(terminal).

Can anyone please suggest a way out?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","-c","java -server -Xmx2g ..."]
```

When you use `sh -c`, it expects a *single* argument that is the command to be run, with spaces separating the arguments, just as if you entered it on the command line. You're currently running just `java` and passing a bunch of additional inappropriate arguments to `sh`.

Also, get rid of the ampersand `&` at the end - you don't want to try and background the process.

Comment: Thank you so much, @jonathon-reinhart. I really appreciate it, especially for the to the point explanation. It worked perfectly fine.