# Dockerfile Spring Boot property from variable not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

I can't seem to get Spring boot properties to work via variable in my Dockerfile. This is what I am doing:

```
ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dapp-version=$app_version -jar /app.jar
```

If I do `RUN echo "App Version: $app_version"` inside of my Dockerfile then I get then I get the correct output like `App Version: 1.70.0`.

If I manually put the version like this: `ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dapp-version=1.70.0 -jar /app.jar` then the value is injected correctly.

In fact, if I do `RUN echo "ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dapp-version=$app_version -jar /app.jar"` then I get output like

```
Step 9/10 : RUN echo "ENTRYPOINT exec java -D******ion=$app_version -jar /app.jar"
 ---> Running in b6c3cd9bb69a
ENTRYPOINT exec java -D******ion=1.70.0 -jar /app.jar
```

The value inside of Spring is being set as an empty string when I use the Dockerfile variable. When I hard code it to 1.70.0 then it is being set correctly. What am I missing?

I have tried many different things including using {}, quotes, etc.

Edit: Added Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
ARG app_version

RUN echo -------------------
RUN echo "App Version: $app_version"
RUN echo -------------------

VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./build/libs/mango-sticky-rice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

ENTRYPOINT exec java -Dapp-version=$app_version -jar /app.jar
```

Comment: Can you paste your entire Dockerfile ?

Comment: I updated my question to include my Dockerfile

Comment: check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904830/3711885

Comment: I actually already saw that answer and my entry point is already setup that way. It is injecting an empty string instead of the actual version because I have a default value inside of my application.yaml file that is being overwritten. My entry point is using the shell form already.

Comment: Have you hardcoded a value to see if gets read in your Java app?

Comment: Yes. If I hard code the value then it is injected correctly into my Spring Boot app.

Comment: How are you setting the variable `app_version`, is it in `pom.xml`?

Comment: docker build --build-arg app_version=<< parameters.app_version >>. This is part of my CircleCI build config. I am 100% sure the value is being passed in because I am echoing it out and am also doing the same thing in a Node project.

Comment: @Gremash, you're not calling a shell that's gonna expand the env vars, replace `exec` by `sh -c`

Comment: I have eddited my answer give it a shot.

Comment: ENTRYPOINT bash -c 'java -Dapp-version=$app_version -jar /app.jar'. That didn't work. I got the same result.

Comment: I think you need to use double quotes for string variable substitution, but give my answer a shot, it's shell neutral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49889134/3088642. This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM java:8
ARG app_version

RUN echo -------------------
RUN echo "App Version: ${app_version}"
RUN echo -------------------

VOLUME /tmp
COPY ./build/libs/mango-sticky-rice-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'

RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n java -Dapp-version=${app_version} -jar /app.jar" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

RUN cat ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```