# Access environment variable value in docker ENTRYPOINT ( exec ) from second parameter(with customerentrypoint script as first parameter)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to access the value of one of `environment` variable in my `dockerfile` , and pass it as first `argument` to the `main script` in docker `ENTRYPOINT`.

I came across [this so link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array/56324100#56324100) which shows two ways to do it. one with `exec form` and one with `shell form`.

The `exec form` worked fine to echo the environment variable with `["sh", "-c", "echo $VARIABLE"]` but when I tried with my custom entrypoint script `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/customentrypoint.sh", "$VARIABLE"]` it is not able to get the value for variable, instead its just taking it as constant `$VARIABLE`.

So I went with `shell form` approach and just called `ENTRYPOINT /bin/customentrypoing "$VARIABLE"`, and  it worked fine to get the value of `$VARIABLE` but It seems that its restricting the no of command line arguments in this case. as I am getting only one value of `$@` even after passing other command line arguments from `docker run`.Can someone please help me if I am doing something wrong , or I should tackle this in different way.Thanks in Advance.

docker looks is similar to

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
...
ENV VARIABLE NO
...
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > /bin/customentrypoint.sh
RUN echo "if  [ "\"\$1\"" = 'YES' ] ; then ; python ${LOCATION}/main.py" \"\$@\" "; else ; echo Please select -e VARIABLE=YES ; fi" >> /bin/customentrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /bin/customentrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s -T /bin/customentrypoint.sh /bin/customentrypoint
WORKDIR ${LOCATION}
ENTRYPOINT /bin/customentrypoint "$VARIABLE"         # - works fine but limits no of command line arguments
# ENTRYPOINT ["bin/customentrypoint", "$VARIABLE"]   # not able to get value of $VARIABLE instead taking as constant.
```

command I am using

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD:/mnt -e VARIABLE=VALUE docker_image:tag entrypoint -d /mnt/tmp -i /mnt/input_file
```

Comment: Maybe the issue is you're doing `$VARIABLE` instead of `$ENVIRONMENT` in the original exec form?

Comment: You don't need to pass environment variables as positional parameters; you can just directly access `$VARIABLE` from within the entrypoint script.

Comment: @DavidMaze , I wanted to change values of `$VARIABLE` in the runtime with ```docker run``` , If I am accessing `$VARIABLE` from within the entrypoint script , I am getting the fixed value which I had during `docker build`

Comment: @ItamarTurner-Trauring , sorry Just updated the question, using `$VARIABLE` in command as well

Comment: The entrypoint doesn't get evaluated or executed until after the `docker run -e` options take effect; you should be able to override `$VARIABLE` at run time.  Including a [mcve] including the Dockerfile and entrypoint script might make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze I have updated with a scaffold of dockerfile I am using.

Answer (score 1):

The environment for `CMD` is interpreted slightly differently depending on how you write the arguments. If you pass the CMD as a string (not inside an array), it gets launched as a shell instead of exec. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd.

What you can try if you want to use array is

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo ${VARIABLE}"]
```

Comment: thansk , but this is already  working fine ,my main question was to get with `ENTRYPOINT ['bin/customerentrypoint, "echo $VARIABLE"]` I have already gone through  https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/

Comment: As you can see in my answer, I have already added the ENTRYPOINT format to achieve that.