# Docker environment variable not making it through on run command to shell script

Tags: docker

I am trying to do exactly as the answers here

[How do I use Docker environment variable in ENTRYPOINT array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array)

but for some reason, it's not working and here is my deploy.sh script..

```
#!/bin/bash
#IF ANY command fails, fail the script
set -e
echo "Deploying $@"
```

This is my Docker file

```
FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine
ENV SERVICE="default"
RUN mkdir -p ./monobuild
COPY . ./monobuild/
WORKDIR "/monobuild"
ENTRYPOINT ./deploy.sh "${SERVICE}"
```

This is my docker run command where I try to feed in SERVICE. ( I would prefer to fail if there is no SERVICE supplied as well)

```
docker run gcr.io/orderly-gcp/prod-deploy -e SERVICE=blah
```

My output however when I run that command is simply

```
Deploying default
```

I am unsure why I follow that sample SO post and this is still not working?

Comment: What OS is this on? Linux?

Comment: Shouldn't there be `-e`  just after `docker run` like this `docker run -e SERVICE=blah gcr.io/orderly-gcp/prod-deploy`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three ways to pass environment variables to docker

---

## First way

Using `-e` flag like `-e ENV_NAME='ENV_VALUE'`

**Example with one environment variable**

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret' -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables**

```
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret' -e MYSQL_DATABASE='mySchema' -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables and many options**

```
docker run --name some-mysql -d -t -i -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret' -e MYSQL_DATABASE='mySchema' mysql:tag
```

> NOTE: You should pass image name `mysql:tag` after options like `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret' -e MYSQL_DATABASE='mySchema'`

---

## Second way

Using `.env` file. basicly you will add environment variables to `.env` file then pass this name to `docker run` command like `docker run --env-file ./.env`

**Example with one environment variable**

Create `.env` file

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

Then use it in docker command

```
docker run --name some-mysql --env-file ./.env -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables**

Create `.env` file

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_DATABASE=mySchema
```

Then use it in docker command

```
docker run --name some-mysql --env-file ./.env -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables and many options**
Create `.env` file

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_DATABASE=mySchema
```

Then use it in docker command

```
docker run --name some-mysql -d -t -i --env-file ./.env mysql:tag
```

> NOTE: You shouldn't add single quote or double quote to the value

> NOTE: You should pass image name `mysql:tag` after options like `--env-file ./.env`

---

## Third way

Using linux environment variables so first we need to explain how to add linux environment variables. there are two type of it (local, global). for example `-e ENV_NAME`.

- Local (per terminal)

To add local environment variables just use `$ export MY_NAME='ahmed'`. then try to retrive it `$ printenv MY_NAME` the result will be `ahmed`.

> NOTE: When you use `$ export MY_NAME='ahmed'` you can use `MY_NAME` in any command in current terminal. so if you try to use it in anther terminal it will not work.

- Local (per command)

To add environment variables to work in current command only just use `$ MY_NAME='ahmed' my_command`. for example `$ MY_NAME='ahmed' printenv MY_NAME` the result will be `ahmed`. so if you try to print `MY_NAME` again it will not work.

- Global (for all terminals)

To add environment variables to work in all terminals just open `~/.bashrc` then add your environment variables like

```
MY_NAME='ahmed'
ENV_NAME='ENV_VALUE'
```

Then try to print it using `printenv MY_NAME` the result will be `ahmed`.

Let's follow the examples.

**Example with one environment variable**

```
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret'
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables**

```
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret'
export MYSQL_DATABASE='mySchema'
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e MYSQL_DATABASE -d mysql:tag
```

**Example with two environment variables and many options**

```
export MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='secret'
export MYSQL_DATABASE='mySchema'
docker run --name some-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e MYSQL_DATABASE -d -t -i mysql:tag
```

> NOTE: You should pass image name `mysql:tag` after options like `-e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e MYSQL_DATABASE`.

---

## Demo

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

ENTRYPOINT ["printenv", "ENV_NAME"]
```

Try to use it

```
$ docker build --tag demo .

$ ENV_NAME='Hello World' docker run -e ENV_NAME demo:latest
$ Hello World

$ docker run -e ENV_NAME='Hello World' demo:latest
$ Hello World
```

Answer (score 3):

The way you are using `run` command is causing the trouble.

`-e` is an option and the way the command should be used is

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

meaning that the `-e` comes before the image name

Answer (score 3):

I think problem is with your `docker run` invocation. It should be like this:

```
docker run -e SERVICE=blah gcr.io/orderly-gcp/prod-deploy
```

From [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint)

> Command line arguments to docker run  will be appended after
> all elements in an exec form ENTRYPOINT, and will override all
> elements specified using CMD. This allows arguments to be passed to
> the entry point, i.e., docker run  -d will pass the -d argument
> to the entry point. You can override the ENTRYPOINT instruction using
> the docker run --entrypoint flag.