# Transfer cucumber.options (tags) as ENV into Docker container

Tags: java, docker, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

Good day everyone.

I have a simple java-based cucumber application, that runs in Docker. I planing to specify which scenarios to run by using ENV for Cucumber tags.

My Dockerfile that able to run specified tags:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-11
COPY target/cucumber-app.jar ./

CMD java -jar -Dcucumber.options='--tags @default' cucumber-app.jar
```

In this case, during docker run command all works perfectly.

I plan to set up a default scenario for not specified Tags and ability to set up special scenarios through ENV:

```
    FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-11
    COPY target/cucumber-app.jar ./
    ENV TAG '--tags @default'
    
    CMD java -jar -Dcucumber.options=$TAG cucumber-app.jar
```

Unfortunately in this case after running docker container I got:

```
Error: could not open `default'
```

Possible you have any ideas why using ENV crash possibility to specify cucumber.options?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array

Comment: You are using the shell form of `CMD` (which implies a `/bin/sh -c` wrapper command), so have you tried adding quotes around your variable? `CMD java -jar -Dcucumber.options="$TAG" cucumber-app.jar`

Comment: @ErikMD Unfortunately any kind of quotes (" ", ' ') doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent version of Cucumber rather then trying to squeeze command line options in through a system property via an environment variable, you can set the environment variable straight away. I.e:

```
ENV CUCUMBER_FILTER_TAGS '@Cucumber and not (@Gherkin or @Zucchini)'
CMD java -jar cucumber-app.jar
```

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/core