# Provide additional input to docker container running inference model

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-sagemaker

We are using AWS Sagemaker feature, bring your own docker, where we have inference model written in R. As I understood, batch transform job runs container in a following way:

```
docker run image serve
```

Also, on docker we have a logic to determine which function to invoke:

```
args <- commandArgs()
if (any(grepl('train', args))) {
    train()}
if (any(grepl('serve', args))) {
    serve()}
```

Is there a way, to override default container invocation so we can pass some additional parameters?

Comment: why don't you pass the additional parameters as hyper parameters?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your response in more details.

Comment: In the docker container your code has access to a SageMaker-created file named hyperparameter.json (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-running-container.html). This contains the hyperparameter value you give to the SDK when launching a training job. So you could use that placeholder to pass parameters needed at training time

Comment: you need to use entrypoint , if I understand what you mean exactly in your Post

Comment: So, to provide more information regarding our case. We create Batch Transform Job using CreateTransformJobRequest using Lambda. There we specify model for inference. This way, we have several models pointing out to several different images on ECR, and we just provide model name when creating batch transform job. Idea is to have one sagemaker model, pointing out to one image, that will contain all inference models in container. Then, somehow in runtime to choose which one to trigger. Initial idea is to check if we can pass additional param. @OlivierCruchant I will look into hyperparameter.json.

Comment: @OlivierCruchant this is for training jobs, but we are running inference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, and is indicated in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html), Sagemaker will run your container with the following command:

```sh
docker run image serve
```

By issuing this command Sagemaker will overwrite any `CMD` that you provide in your container Dockerfile, so you cannot use `CMD` to provide dynamic arguments to your program.

We can think in use the Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` to consume some environment variables, but the documentation of AWS dictates that it is preferable use the `exec` form of the `ENTRYPOINT`. Somethink like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/Rscript", "/opt/ml/mars.R", "--no-save"]
```

I think that, for analogy with [model training](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-training-algo-dockerfile.html), they need this kind of container execution to enable the container to receive termination signals:

> The exec form of the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction starts the executable directly, not as a child of `/bin/sh`. This enables it to receive signals like `SIGTERM` and `SIGKILL` from SageMaker APIs.

To allow variable expansion, we need to use the `ENTRYPOINT` `shell` form. Imagine:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "/usr/bin/Rscript", "/opt/ml/mars.R", "--no-save", "$ENV_VAR1"]
```

If you try to do the same with the `exec` form the variables provided will be treated as a literal and will not be sustituited for their actual values.

Please, see the approved answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array) stackoverflow question for a great explanation of this subject.

But, one thing you can do is obtain the value of these variables in your R code, similar as when you process `commandArgs`:

```r
ENV_VAR1 <- Sys.getenv("ENV_VAR1")
```

To pass environment variables to the container, as indicated in the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/your-algorithms-batch-code.html), you can use the [`CreateModel`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateModel.html) and [`CreateTransformJob`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html) requests on your container.

You probably will need to include in your Dockerfile `ENV` definitions for every required environment variable on your container, and provide for these definitions default values with `ARG`:

```
ARG ENV_VAR1_DEFAULT_VALUE=VAL1
ENV_VAR1=$ENV_VAR1_DEFAULT_VALUE
```

Comment: At the end I've done this using env variables passed to container, using CreateTransformJobRequest and property Environment. In R script I've read them using following line env_var1 <- Sys.getenv("ENV_VAR1"). This approach worked fine.

Comment: I am very happy to know that the answer was helpful.

Comment: @jccampanero Do you know of any way to add the `--privileged` flag to the docker run command?

Comment: Hi Austin. Honestly no, but I'm afraid you can't elevate the container in Sagemaker, for two reasons: first, they run your container and you have no control over it, that's the point of this specific question; and more importantly, they provide a managed environment your container will run in: if they gave you the ability to run your container in privileged mode, unless they remap your container root user - I think they won't o that - you have full control over the host environment in which the container is running with the security implications it could have.