# Override ENTRYPOINT configuration in Micronaut Gradle Dockerfile

Tags: docker, micronaut

I'm running a Micronaut application as a Docker container.

At runtime in Kuberentes there will be a JAVA_OPTS environment variable with certaint values, e.g.: `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage=45.0`

When executing `./gradlew dockerBuild` I can see the following Docker layer:

`Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/home/app/application.jar"]`

Following the [documentation](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gradle-plugin/latest/#_docker_support) I tried to add a reference to JAVA_OPTS:

build.gradle.kts

```
    dockerfile {
        args("\$JAVA_OPTS")
    }
```

Docker build log:

```
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["java", "$JAVA_OPTS", "-jar", "/home/app/application.jar"]
```

The problem with this, is that the container wont's start, since $JAVA_OPTS won't be replaced by the env variable value. This happens because it is using the [exec form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904830) of the ENTRYPOINT.

Is there a way to override or tune the ENTRYPOINT so that env vars are evaluated?

Comment: As demonstrated in the other question you linked, you could `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/app/application.jar"]`

Comment: The question is how to configure Micronaut to change the entrypoint

Comment: Overflying the documentation you linked, I came across the following link that might be clearer to you than to myself: https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/763dc3e6117a6c486893ec5fc1a6275eb06ae9d3/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/tasks/image/Dockerfile.groovy#L753

Comment: I think that won't work, the documentation shows an example: `The produced instruction looks as follows: ENTRYPOINT ["top", "-b"]`

Comment: ...`entryPoint('sh', '-c', 'java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/app/application.jar')` => `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/app/application.jar"]` ???

Comment: Oops, you're right, that'll work. I you add that info as an answer I'll be glad to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [link in your documentation](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin/blob/763dc3e6117a6c486893ec5fc1a6275eb06ae9d3/src/main/groovy/com/bmuschko/gradle/docker/tasks/image/Dockerfile.groovy#L753), it looks like you can do something like the following to override the entrypoint according to your requirement to interpret the env var in the command:

```
entryPoint('sh', '-c', 'java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/app/application.jar')
```

It should translate to the following in the generated Dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar /home/app/application.jar"]
```