# Run Shell script in docker using Environment variable

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, docker-entrypoint

I am running a docker file to execute a debezium service as entrypoint.

It works fine and executes debezium service when I use the exact file path as parameter to Entrypoint command in my docker file

command in docker file

ENTRYPOINT ["kafka_2.12-2.6.2/bin/connect-standalone.sh","kafka_2.12-2.6.2/config/connect-standalone.properties","kafka_2.12-2.6.2/worker.properties"]

**But it fails when I pass the file names as environment variable**

command in docker file

ENTRYPOINT [${connect_standalone},${connect_standalone_properties},${worker_properties}]

docker run command

sudo docker run -it -e connect_standalone=kafka_2.12-2.6.2/bin/connect-standalone.sh -e connect_standalone_properties=kafka_2.12-2.6.2/config/connect-standalone.properties -e worker_properties=kafka_2.12-2.6.2/worker.properties --name cloud1 cloud9-image:latest

output of the docker run command

/bin/sh: [kafka_2.12-2.6.2/bin/connect-standalone.sh,kafka_2.12-2.6.2/config/connect-standalone.properties,kafka_2.12-2.6.2/worker.properties]: No such file or directory

**Somehow it always goes to /bin/sh even though I have set working directory as root of my container where the kafka_2.12-2.6.2 directory is present**

Comment: Try the solutions from here, I think it will be enough for you to add double quotes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array

Comment: `connect-distributed` is already the default entrypoint for existing Kafka Connect Docker images... why are you trying to run standalone?

Comment: @KubePony, I tried that solution but if I enclose everything in double quotes then variable doesn't get substituted with value I passed while running docker

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "${connect_standalone}": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: @OneCricketeer
because we are running kafka connect locally in single Ec2 machine as part of POC

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Connect distributed doesn't require more than one instance

Answer (score 0):

Replacing environment variables in a command is the job of the shell. When you use the *exec* form of the ENTRYPOINT statement, there is no shell to replace them, so it doesn't work.

You need to use the *shell* form which starts a shell to run the command. Then then shell will replace the variables and it should work.

So instead of

```
ENTRYPOINT [${connect_standalone},${connect_standalone_properties},${worker_properties}]
```

do

```
ENTRYPOINT ${connect_standalone} ${connect_standalone_properties} ${worker_properties}
```

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: [ bracket is missing in your suggestion and it won't work, I looked at documentation and I tried everything but it fails. It looks like Entrypoint requires complete string and no dynamic variable unless if it's required to just print a string on console

Comment: I'd forgotten to delete the ending `]` bracket. Sorry. There should be no brackets.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest an alternative?

Your executable and the worker properties don't really need to change, so there's no reason to use environment variables here.

If you want to change worker properties using environment variables, then that's what existing Connect containers can do...

```
WORKDIR "kafka_2.12-2.6.2" 
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/connect-standalone.sh", "config/connect-standalone.properties"]
```

Now, if you want the option to run any number of connectors at *runtime*, but default to a specific one, then that's a CMD

```
CMD ["connector.properties"]
```

Build the image

If you want to use a different file, mount it as a Docker volume over `kafka_2.12-2.6.2/connector.properties`

If you want to run multiple connectors, mount a directory of property files

```
docker run --rm -v $HOME/connectors:/work:ro your_image /work/connector-1.properties /work/connector-2.properties
```

Remove the `CMD` if you don't want a default connector