# docker shell form entrypoint not replacing variable if not provided by `docker run`

Tags: docker, variables, environment-variables

I was looking at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904830/169252 to try to solve my problem.

However, it doesn't seem to work for my case

```
ENV API="list,create,delete"
ENV ID="1-1"
ENV VERBO=5

ENTRYPOINT /myapp --id=$ID --api=$API --origin="*" --trace --metrics --verbosity=$VERBO  --allow-insecure
```

However, I always get `invalid value "" for flag -verbosity:` if not provided by the `docker run` command, i.e.

`docker run -p 80:8080 $DOCKER_IMAGE`.

However, if I run it as

`docker run -p 80:8080 -e VERBO=4 $DOCKER_IMAGE`, it seems to work (have another issue right now after this so can't post actual result).

Am I using this correctly? The idea is that `VERBO` is an optional argument and doesn't need to be set by `docker run` -only if so desired.

This is the complete Dockerfile:

```
  FROM golang:1.19-alpine as builder    
               
  RUN apk add --no-cache make gcc musl-dev linux-headers git    
      
  WORKDIR /go/myapp    
  COPY . .    
      
  ARG GOPROXY    
  RUN go mod download    
  RUN make myapp    
              
              
  ENV API="list,create,delete"    
  ENV ID="1-1"    
  ENV VERBO=5             
      
  FROM alpine:latest    
      
  RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates    
      
  COPY --from=builder /go/myapp/build/myapp /    
                 
  ENTRYPOINT /myapp --id=$ID --api=$API --origin="*" --trace --metrics --verbosity=$VERBO  --allow-insecure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of `ENV VERBO=5` is correct and sets the default to 5.

To troubleshoot the problem, run the container and inspect it:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 $DOCKER_IMAGE
docker ps -a
docker container inspect <container-id>
```

Within the `Config` dictionary, check the value of `Env` list that should contan also `VERBO=5`.

```
 "Env": [
     "PATH=...",
     "VERBO=5"
 ]
```

If there is that key-value means you've set the default value correctly.

Checking your Dockerfile, your issue is related to the multiple declaration of the base image (`FROM` command) that creates multiple contexts in your container.
So, the VERBO value is not global and you need to set the default value also in the second part:

```
...
FROM alpine:latest
ENV VERBO=5
...
```

Comment: What I am saying is that if I start it like that: `docker run -p 80:8080 $DOCKER_IMAGE`, then my container doesn't even boot, with the "invalid value" error I described in the question.

Only if I explicitly provide the env var with -e it seems to pick it: `docker run ... -e VERBO=4 $DOCKER_IMAGE`

Comment: Could you please share the Dockerfile you're using?

Comment: I added the complete file to the question.

Comment: I edited my answer with the line to add in order to solve your issue.