# Launch Jupyter ECS Fargate with password stored in AWS Secrets manager

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, jupyter-lab, aws-secrets-manager

I have successfully managed to run a Jupyter Lab on ECS by using Terraform.

I want to protect the setup by using a password stored in AWS secrets manager.

The point is that the parameter NotebookApp.password accept an encoded string, while the value in secrets manager is plain text.
This is a fragment of my working configuration showing part of container_definitions:

```
    "secrets": [{
      "name": "JUPYTER_PASSWORD",
      "valueFrom": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:........"
    }],
    "mountPoints": [{
        "sourceVolume": "jupyter-efs-volume",
        "containerPath": "/home/jovyan/notebooks",
        "readOnly": false
      }
    ],
    "entryPoint": [
      "start-notebook.sh",
      "--no-browser",
      "--NotebookApp.notebook_dir=/home/jovyan/notebooks",
      "--NotebookApp.password=?????", <----- what to put here
      "--NotebookApp.token=''",
      "--NotebookApp.allow_origin=${"'*'"}",
      "--NotebookApp.ip='0.0.0.0'"
    ],
```

Based on the example above, I am having two problems:

1. How can I refer the variable JUPYTER_PASSWORD in NotebookApp.password ?
2. As a workaround I know I could encode the password in secret manager. Is there a way to instruct the container at startup to encode the retrieved password ?

If I hard code the hashed password, it works:

```
"--NotebookApp.password='argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=10240,t=10,p=8$mi....'"
```

if I reference the env variable it doesn't work. The double sign $$ is for Terraform to be able to escape it correctly. These are the unsuccesful tentatives by now:

```
"--NotebookApp.password='$${JUPYTER_PASSWORD}'"
```

and without single quotes

```
"--NotebookApp.password=$${JUPYTER_PASSWORD}"
```

**UPDATE**

By running Exec command I have verified that the environment variable is correctly configured at ECS level:

```
Starting session with SessionId: ecs-execute-command-xxxxxxx
# echo $JUPYTER_PASSWORD
argon2:$argon2id$v=19$m=......
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `?????` part to `${JUPYTER_PASSWORD}` to reference the environment variable named `JUPYTER_PASSWORD` that is being injected into the container with the secret value.

Comment: there must be something that Terraform is doing, because if I hard code the hashed password it works, if instead I refer to the env variable it doesn't. I have updated the question.

Comment: What is the error message when it doesn't work? You should probably use ECS Exec to get into the container to verify the environment variable has the value you think it does, without any extra characters or whitespace or anything. If you think Terraform is doing something wrong, go into the AWS web console and look at the created task definition to see what the `entryPoint` value is there. I don't think this is a Terraform issue since you are correctly escaping the `$` with `$$`.

Comment: No error, just "invalid credentials". I will give a try to ECS exec if available and update the question consequently. The log seems to be fine with Jupyter starting correctly.

Comment: After some investigation, it seems to me that entrypoint and command are not meant to parse environment variables. Which is if one pass ${MY_VAR} this will be intended as a literal "$MY_VAR" no substitution is performed at this stage.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. It looks like there are some things you can do to make environment variables work in the Entrypoint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904682/how-do-i-use-docker-environment-variable-in-entrypoint-array